# File Reader resolve before another function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, filereader, synchronous

I am doing a file uploader, where you also fill some text and select the file. Then you press the submit button. The problem I have is that all the other parts are finishing before the filereader so the variable is undefined.

This is the code of the button

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick = "processFile();submitDiagnosis(this,`+index+`)">Submit</button>
```

As you see its calling the function process file and submitDiagnosis

This is processFile(), that is calling readFileAsync that uses promise to load the file

```
    async function processFile(){
      try{
        const photo = document.getElementById("photo").files[0];
        const ipfs = window.IpfsApi('localhost', 5001) // Connect to IPFS
        let contentBuffer = await readFileAsync(photo);
        const buf = buffer.Buffer(contentBuffer) // Convert data into buffer
        ipfs.files.add(buf, (err, result) => { // Upload buffer to IPFS
          if(err) {
            console.error(err)
            return
          }
        window.enlace = `http://127.0.0.1:8080/ipfs/${result[0].hash}`
          })
      } catch(err){
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
```

Then readFileAsync is this one

```
    function readFileAsync(file) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onloadend =() => {
          resolve (reader.result);
        };

        reader.onerror = reject;

        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

      });

    }
```

And finally submitDiagnosis is this one

```
  function submitDiagnosis(element,index)
    {
        urle = window.enlace;
        var table = document.getElementById("viewPatient");
        var patientAddress = table.rows[index].cells[1].innerHTML;

        //console.log(patientAddress);
        // var dropSelect = document.getElementById("ailmentsList"+patientAddress);
        var diagnosis = $("#ailmentsList"+patientAddress).val();
        diagnosis = parseInt(diagnosis);
        var diagnosed = ailmentsDict[diagnosis];
        var comments = document.getElementById("details").value;

        var oldRecords = $("#records"+patientAddress).html();

        var today = new Date();
        var date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();
        var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
        var dateTime = date+' '+time;


        var newRecords =
`Diagnosed By : ${docName}
Doctor's Public Key : ${key}
Time : ${dateTime}
Diagnosis : ${diagnosed}
Comments : ${comments}
File : ${urle}

`
```

The problem that I have is that I need the var urle defined and with the value of the link by the time it gets to submitDiagnosis, but I cannot get it to happen. As right now I know its getting defined  after the diagnosis is submitted, as if I run it a second time it does show up as defined .

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem comes from the fact you synchronously called two functions, but one is async. Just a suggestion, but have you tried to do something like this ?

```
async function processAndSubmitFile() {
    await processFile();
    await submitDiagnosis();
}
```

and so you call that function onclick of your button.

Hope it will help you!

Comment: Yeah I had not thought about that. I implemented your suggestions and added promise on some parts. And now it works! Thank you

Comment: Glad I can help! Happy hacking ;)